# Unable to find "StreamingCompletions" and "deploymentOrModelName" while consuming OPenAI in c# from azure

Tags: openai-api

I working with OpenAI and deployed model, while consuming the model in C# console application I am facing the issue with "StreamingCompletions" and "deploymentOrModelName". These classes are not available and I copied the code from generated by azure model which is availble in the portal.

How can we get the classes "StreamingCompletions" and "deploymentOrModelName"? Do we need to any nuget packages?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `deploymentOrModelName` is a [named parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments). And yes, SDK-s have to be installed before they can be used. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/supported-languages

Comment: Installed it , but these classes are not recognizing